# Validating widget's configuration data on Admin page

Tags: widgets, wp-admin, validation

I have a simple widget that needs its width and height set by the user, so that it is displayed properly on the blog.

The thing is: on the **Administrator/Appearance/Widgets** page, if the admin user puts something like "400px" on the width, it works perfectly. But what if the user puts "xxxx"?

Is there any way that I can fire some javascript when the user presses the "Save" button, so as **to inform the user that the data is invalid**? I looked all around for hooks on the save button, or ways to intercept the submit, but found nothing.

Am I looking at this problem from a wrong perspective? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest only storing the numeric value and provide a checkbox or dropdown to determine whether to use pixels or a percentage(or if only ever px, just add that when you run the display code). A numeric value alone is easier validate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@tf is almost there, I think. You *can* use JS on your widget's admin form, as I've done it before (though not for validation).

Within your widget's constructor, add an action:

```
add_action( "admin_print_scripts-widgets.php", array( __CLASS__, 'register_my_validation_script' ) );
```

Then create the corresponding function inside your widget's class:

```
function register_my_validation_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script-handle', plugins_url( '/my-validation-script.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' );
}
```

This assumes your JS is a script (`my-validation-script.js`) inside your plugin's directory.

Within that JS script is your jQuery to execute your validation. This is where the pseudo code begins...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.widget-control-save').on('click', function() {
// check this is the right widget - probably using something like $(this).closest('form').width-field...
// validate stuff
    });
});
```

Comment: There's little point in registering a script for a single call, just outright do the enqueue for single use scripts. Additionally, as of jQuery 1.7 `live` is deprecated and should be replaced with `on`.

Comment: True, answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit tricky to get the ID fropm the form because it is created dynamically. Normally I use this JS to trigger an event when the save button is pressed:

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function($) {
        $( '.widget-control-save' ).on( 'click',
            function() {
                // grab the ID of the save button
                var saveID   = $( this ).attr( 'id' );

                // grab the 'global' ID
                var ID       = saveID.replace( /-savewidget/, '' );

            }
        );
    }
);
```

You are a good guy and so you use `get_field_id()` and `get_field_name()` in you widget code, hm!?

```
printf(
  '<input type="text" id="%s" name="%s" value="%d" />',
  $this->get_field_id( 'width' ),
  $this->get_field_name( 'width' ),
  (int) $instance['width']
);
```

The ID of your input field is something like `your-widget-name-[number]-width`. The problem is the number, it differs everytime you add or remove a widget to/from the sidebar. In the JS above, the variable `ID` now got the value `your-widget-name-[number]` (e.g. `your-widget-name[2]`). So you just have to add `-width` to the `ID` and can grab the value of the input field

```
var width = $( '#' + ID + '-width' ). val();
// validate the value of the input field with parseInt() or something else
```

But if I expect a number, then I would not let the user input chars. It's not a problem to prevent the user from typing chars.

```
add_filter( 'widget_form_callback', 'prevent_char_input', 1, 2 );

function prevent_char_input( $instance, $object ) {

// assuming your widgets id is 'foo_widget'
if ( 'foo_widget' !== $object->id_base || ! is_integer( $object->number ) )
    return $instance;

echo "
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

    var input = $( '#widget-{$object->id}-width' );

    input.keydown(function(event) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
        if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });

  } );</script>";

    return $instance;
}
```

So what we do here is, printing some inline script. The PHP function checks everytime when a html form inside a widget is printed, if the widget name match and if the widget number is an integer. We use the object propperties `id_base` and `id`. The `id_base` is the id you use when registering the widget. The `id` is the widget-id plus the number in the sidebar (e.g. `foo_widget-2`).

Best practise is to avoid the inline script. You can create a jQuery extension and enqueue it into the footer. This reduce the inline script to `$( '#widget-{$object->id}-width' ).numbersOnly();` and in the javascript something like:

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.numbersOnly = function() {

    this.keydown(function() {
      [... code here ...]
    });

  };
})( jQuery );
```

I hope this helps you a bit to find the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not WP-specific.

Your widget most likely already has a form. That form has a name/ID (if not, give it one).

What you want to do is check `onsubmit` of the form for certain conditions.

Suppose that is your form:

```
<form name="myWidgetForm" ... >
    <input type="number" name="width" />
    <input type="number" name="height" />
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

So first change the form as follows:

```
<form name="myWidgetForm" ... onsubmit="return validateMyWidgetForm()">
```

Then provide the following JavaScript function (either in a separate JS file that has to be enqueued, or hard-coded):

**Plain JavaScript**

```
function validateMyWidgetForm() {
    var msg = "";

    if (document.forms["myWidgetForm"]["width"].value < 400)
        msg = msg + "The value of 'width' has to be greater than 400.\n";

    if (document.forms["myWidgetForm"]["height"].value < 600)
        msg = msg + "The value of 'height' has to be greater than 600.\n";

    ...

    if ("" != msg) {
        alert(msg);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Note**: The above function is not copy-and-paste-ready, but for demonstration purposes only.

---

Alternative **jQuery** version

```
function validateMyWidgetForm() {
    var msg = "";

    if (jQuery('#myWidgetForm #width').val() < 400)
        msg = msg + "The value of 'width' has to be greater than 400.\n";

    if (jQuery('#myWidgetForm #height').val() < 600)
        msg = msg + "The value of 'height' has to be greater than 600.\n";

    ...

    if ("" != msg) {
        alert(msg);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @t f, thanks for the incredibly fast answer!
The way wordpress works, the form name is not in my control. The widget function "form ($instance)" only gives me control of a div inside the form.
I am now searching for a way to create a name for the form and to intercept the save button - that is also not inside my control.

Comment: I haven't developed any widgets so far, but both giving the form a name and defining the `onsubmit` attribute is also possible by jQuery (if not during the widget creation process).

Comment: Well, thanks, t f, for the ideas. But any attempt at javascript on my widget's admin form completely breaks the whole Administrator/Appearance/Widgets page. I still believe it is possible, but it seems I will have to deal with a lot of existing Ajax before I'm able to make it.

Comment: @tf The problem with the widgest on the widgets page is, the IDs of each form is generated dynamically. So you cannot really predict what ID the form will have.